# iOS simulator options changes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

When I open any song site through simulator of iPhone or iPad say mp3skull.com . and when i click on option `download` It gives me the Alertview option to `COPY` and `OPEN` . IS there any way I can give one more option in this .say `open copy download`. for more clarity shown in page :

[image]

Comment: Just wonder how do you make a iPhone device frame into a simulator?

Answer (score 0):

1st off: I no not think that adding a specific item there is possbile.

Now assuming you actually want to add a "Download" button, consider this:

1. Opening a file by default means you have to download the file first
2. "Download" on a PC/Mac just puts the file into a "known" folder where you can open it with any program later while "open" puts it into a (possibly) random temp folder and then runs the default program
3. Due to the nature of safari in iOS a "Download" button would be more like "Store in Safari for later"
4. Open in safari is -> Download, Store, Ask user what app he wants to use to open the file type.

So considering the above points I do not see how a "Download" button would function. If you have some more details what you want your button to do, maybe there is an alternative that will work for you.